# youtube.playlistItems.insert(..) spends a lot of quota

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use some Youtube api v3 methods. Everyone spends units (quota) according to the documentation. The method for inserting videos to a playlist should spend 2 units. But for 9 requests spent 530 units.

What is the problem?

```js
function addVideoToWL(vId) {
  return gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
    "part": "snippet",
    "resource": {
      "snippet": {
        "playlistId": "WL",
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": vId
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert

Comment: Request spend 53 units. Why? 
It's bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quota calculator. It says that inserting costs 53 units.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert